# The difference between the ways of declaring a variable

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C, and I can not understand what is the difference between the declaration of variables (firstString, secondString and thirdString) in MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSString *firstString;
}
@end
```

in MyClass.m:

```
@interface MyClass() {
    NSString *secondString;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

NSString *thirdString;

@end
```

I guess that the first and the second case is the same thing, but in what case it is better to use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the three, it's mainly visibility control.

1. The first one is declared in a public header of you class, that means that you want the programmers the know about the variable. If the access to this property is restricted (e.g. `@private`), it should not appear in public header anymore and you should use the second or forth option.
2. The second is declared in the class continuation, meaning that it is needed only by the implementation.
3. The third one is a global variable, something you should use only in exceptional cases.
4. Missing another option

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSString *thirdString; 
}

@end
```

(allowed by the latest Apple compilers) is the same as 2, without the need to  create the class continuation.

Comment: The third option is not an ivar.

Answer (score 3):

`firstString` is declared in the header, the file which is `#import`ed by other classes. It is exposed to other classes and can therefore be accessed by subclasses and, since the symbol is available in the header file, it will be simpler for external objects to alter through [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1).

`secondString` is declared in your implementation file. The `()` in `@interface MyClass ()` signifies that this is a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3). `secondString` will not be exposed to external classes (though, as with everything in Objective-C, you cannot consider it to be truly private).

Comment: "It is exposed to (and can therefore be written/read by) other classes." - Wrong, instance variables are `@protected` by default. To do what you described, they must be declared `@public` explicitly.

Comment: @H2CO3 Still it can be accessed by subclasses.

Comment: @H2CO3: and also can be accessed via key-value coding `[myInstance setValue:@"newString" forKey:@"firstString"]`. That aspect of the answer as is, though, is rather broad and vague; could use some clarification...

Comment: @NSGod the KVC access is possible for all ivars, never mind where they are declared.

Comment: @all. Yes, clarity was needed here. Hope these alterations meet with your (collective) approval :)

Answer (score 2):

The first and second variables will be instance variables, whereas the third one will be a file-scope global variable. Typically you should use instance variables and avoid using global variables.

Comment: File-scope and global sounds contradicting. It's just a normal global variable with linker-exported symbol.